# Getting the value inside of a file and putting the value inside of a variable using CreateFile

Tags: c++, windows, api

I'm trying to make a code that will read multiple URLs and put each value of the URLs in a variables using windows API `ReadFile`.

For example

**Variables**

`string urlone;`

`string urltwo;`

**Inside of url.txt**

`www.stackoverflow.com`

`www.reddit.com`

My concern is that is it possible to get the values and put it in a variables using `ReadFile` or any windows API functions?

from the example above, what will happen is `stackoverflow.com` will become the value of variable `urlone` same with the next URL which is `reddit.com` will become the value of variable `urltwo`.

I know that using `fstream` will help me to solve this but I just want to know if there are any other way like using windows API.

Note: I tried to use `ReadFile` and it gets all the URLs and put the value inside of 1 variable.

```
//reading url.txt
openFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\url.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

//reading the content, on this code, all the URLs will be inside of strVal
rewriFile = ReadFile(openFile, strVal, fSize, &dwNoBytetoRead, NULL);
cout << "The URL is " << strVal << endl;
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: You still have the bug you had before.  Repeating, ReadFile() is low-level and only reads bytes.  Not strings.  The "strVal" variable won't have a properly zero-terminated string.  dwNoBytetoRead tells you where to put the 0.  Splitting up the bytes into lines of text is something else it will not do.  The standard C++ library does that for you, std::getline() is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can solve it using `ReadFile` if you want to. Using `ReadFile` a simpel approach could be:

1. read entire file using `ReadFile` into a buffer (I suggest to use
   `std::string` and `resize`)
2. use whatever to parse the string, for simpel parsing,
   `std::istringstream` can be used

Coincidently, if the `std::istringstream` is good enough for parsing your format (im 99% sure that it is), then that may be the case where the `std` stream classes really shines since then you could use a `std::ifstream` to do both !